# Maven compiler plugin fails using automatic java 9 modules

Tags: java, maven, module

I'm trying to compile a java 9 maven project, but the compiling fails giving me the following error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project WebApp: Compilation failure: 
Compilation failure:
[ERROR] D:/Projects/WebApp/src/main/java/module-info.java:[9,33] module not found: java.persistence
```

This is the part of my POM.xml containing the maven-compiler-plugin:

```
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
          <configuration>
               <source>9</source>
               <target>9</target>
               <compilerArgs>
                   <arg>-classpath</arg>
                   <arg>${project.build.directory}/target/classes</arg>
                   <arg>--module-path=${dependencies.dir}</arg>
               </compilerArgs>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

The dependencies are copied to `${dependencies.dir}` before compiling. The dependency making problems is an automatic module.

Comment: Is there a persistence jar file there defining the `java.persistence` module?

Comment: Yes, there is, I checked using java --module-path=./ --List-modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by removing all compiler args entries.